# Curious sequences associated to continuous fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, experimental-mathematics

Given a strictly positive initial rational number $x_0$ in $\mathbb Q_>$
we define a sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ recursively by
setting $x_{n+1}=x_n+1/S(x_n)$
for $S(x)=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_k$
where $[a_0;a_1,\ldots]$ is the rational fraction expansion of
$x=a_0+1/(a_1+1/\ldots)$. (A rational number has of course two such expansions with equal sums.)

The rational sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ is clearly increasing and converges therefore to a limit $L(x_0)$ in $(0,\infty)\cup\lbrace +\infty\rbrace$.

Experimentally one gets a curious behaviour: For simple rational values of $x_0$, the limit $L(x_0)$ is either an integer (and convergency is extremely fast: at some stage, the number of digits of $S(x_i)$ essentiantly doubles at each iteration) or convergency is slow and $L(x_0)$ can not be guessed numerically.

A few preimages of $L$ for small integers are:

$$L^{-1}(1)\supset\lbrace 1/5,2/5,3/7,4/7\rbrace,$$
$$L^{-1}(2)\supset\lbrace 3/2,4/3,7/4,7/5\rbrace,$$
$$L^{-1}(3)\supset\lbrace 1,2,1/2,1/3,2/3,1/4,3/4,3/5,4/5,5/2,1/6,5/6,5/7,6/7\rbrace,$$
$$L^{-1}(4)\supset\lbrace 3,7/2\rbrace.$$

A few initial values with bad convergency are $4,5,7,8,9,1/7,2/7,7/3,7/6$.

*Can one say something interesting
about the set of values $L(\mathbb Q_>)$?*

**Remark:** For negative rational values $x_0$ one gets sometimes into trouble (division by $S(x_i)=0$ at some stage). In the remaining cases the sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ is no longer
increasing and can be eventually periodic: $x_0=-3$ leads to
$$-3,-10/3,-13/3,-29/6,-23/6,-10/3,\ldots\ .$$